# Can one force a linear regression fit to go through the origin?

Tags: fitting

As the question says, can one force a fit through the origin $(0,0)$, as one can when fitting a trendline to your data in Microsoft Excel? If so, how do you do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
data = Table[{i, 3 i + RandomReal[2]}, {i, 10}]
line = Fit[data, {x}, x]
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[line, {x, 0, 10}], PlotLabel -> line]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Also: `LinearModelFit[..., IncludeConstantBasis -> False]`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. also `Minimize[Sum[(i[[2]] - a i[[1]])^2, {i, data}], a]` and zillions more :)

Comment: Yes, that surely fits the description of "force"! :)

Answer (score 15):

Another possibility, a bit more general :

```
data = Table[{i, 3 i + RandomReal[2]}, {i, 10}];

model[x_] = a Cos[x] + b x^2 + c;

sol = FindFit[data, {model[x]}, {a, b, c}, x];
```

One can add constraints on the parameters to the model :

```
sol2 = FindFit[data, {model[x], model[0] == 0}, {a, b, c}, x];

Show[ListPlot[data],  Plot[{model[x] /. sol, model[x] /. sol2}, {x, 0, 10}]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Important consideration with this approach: the interior point method (which is used for all constrained fits unless `Method -> NMinimize` is specified) requires that the residual and any additional constraints be twice differentiable, preferably analytically. If not, it will usually have trouble converging.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Good point,  thanks, I was not aware of this - is it in the documentation ?

Comment: Sort of--you can find it discussed in relation to `FindMinimum` [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLocalNumerical.html#417182119).

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for answering. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 7):

I have given a derivation of the needed formulae in [this math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/180759). As already mentioned by belisarius, the canonical method for finding the equation of the least-squares line constrained to pass through the origin in *Mathematica* would be either of

```
Fit[data, {x}, x]
```

which produces the explicit linear function, or

```
FindFit[data, m x, m, x]
```

which produces just the slope of the best-fit line as a replacement rule.

To handle the case of a least-squares line constrained to pass through an *arbitrary* point $(h,k)$, you can again use either of `Fit[]` or `FindFit[]`, but things are slightly trickier. (I'll leave the task of encapsulating that method in a *Mathematica* routine as an exercise.) For this answer, I'll present the explicit formula, as implemented in *Mathematica*:

```
fixedLine[data_?MatrixQ, pt : (_?VectorQ) : {0, 0}] := Module[{a, b, dat, sx, sy},
  dat = If[Precision[data] === Infinity, N[data], data];
  {sx, sy} = Transpose[dat] - pt;
  b = sx.sy/sx.sx;
  a = #2 - b #1 & @@ pt;
  Function[\[FormalX], Evaluate[Chop[a + b \[FormalX]]]]]
```

This returns the best-fit line as a pure function. Here are a few examples, taken from Kolb's *Curve Fitting for Programmable Calculators*:

```
fixedLine[{{100, 140}, {200, 230}, {300, 310}, {400, 400}, {500, 480}}, {300, 310}]
   Function[\[FormalX]$, 55. + 0.85 \[FormalX]$]

fixedLine[{{11, 15}, {17, 23}, {23, 31}, {29, 39}}]
   Function[\[FormalX]$, 1.34831 \[FormalX]$]
```

Comment: Thank you J.M. for answering my question.

Answer (score 7):

*belisarius* gives the solution but forgot to tell *why* it is the solution.

The general equation for your linear regression line is

$y = a x + b$

which you write in the `Fit` function as

```
line = Fit[data, {x, 1}, x]
```

The second parameter is a list of functions. Fit will find the best fit by making a weighted sum of these functions, i.e.

$ a_1 \cdot x + a_2 \cdot 1 $

If you want a line through the origin the constant term should be zero, and the `Fit` becomes

```
line = Fit[data, {x}, x]
```

Example:

```
data = Table[{i, 10 + 3 i + RandomReal[2]}, {i, 10}];
line1 = Fit[data, {1, x}, x]
line2 = Fit[data, {x}, x]
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]], 
     Plot[{line1, line2}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick]]
```

gives us

> ```
> 11.673984 + 2.9005496 x  
> 4.5682616 x
> ```

[image: points and best-fit lines]

Comment: Thank you very much stevenh for the clarification.